# How to add text between price and short description in WordPress (WooCommerce)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have next problem. I need to add text after price of the product and before short description. This text can be added in short description on first line like an option. The text that I want to add show the same price without 3% of itself.

I put this code in function.php of my current theme:

```
   add_action('woocommerce_short_description','wire_price_3',11);
   function wire_price_3()
   {
        $product = wc_get_product();
    $product_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $percent_3 = ($price_p *3)/100;
        $percet_price = $product_price - $percent_3;
    echo "<h1>Wire price: {$percet_price}</h1>";
    echo "\n";
   }
```

Eveythring works well but when I add this code my checkout page become a mess and show some code.

So, my question is how to find solution to this problem? BTW how can I make to show your text this text for example in green color.

Thank you.

Comment: Why `{$percet_price}` and not `".$percet_price."` ?

Comment: And it probably should be `($product_price *3)/100`

Comment: Yes, you're right about  ($product_price *3)/100 but this one {$percet_price} works well. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

i have changed your code, please try if it works properly

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'mx_price_per_installments_w_fee', 30 );
function mx_price_per_installments_w_fee() {
    global $product;
    $price = (float) $product->get_price();
    $feeextended = (3/100) * $price;
    $price4extendedinstallments = $price - $feeextended;
   echo "
   <div id='installments-container'>
       <div id='installments-text'>
        <div class='bold'>Wire price: <span class='success'>". number_format($price4extendedinstallments, 2, ",", ".") ." €.</span></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks) THis code works well. But how can I make different color for "wire price" text? Where I have to describe styles in functons.php or what?

Comment: in css through the theme

Comment: So, I go to style.css add this code:

.installments-container {
 color: #d1aa67;
}
.installments-text {
 color: #d1aa67;
}
.bold {
 color: #d1aa67;
}
.success {
 color: #d1aa67;
}

But there is no any effect on text. What did I do wrong?

Comment: if you want the text to be a different color, it is enough to add it to the css of the theme (I don't know which one you are using, you may have entered the syntax in the wrong css) just this code #installments-text {    font-weight: bold;
    color: #d1aa67;
}

if you want the value to be of a different color, then add this too
#installments-text {    font-weight: bold;
    color: #d1aa67;
}
#installments-text .success { color: red}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything works well. The only thing is remaining. My "wire price" is showing after "add to cart" button. And I need to show this "wire price" exactly after main  price on the new line. Can you tell what way I need to go to make this possible?

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ,'mx_price_per_installments_w_fee', 30 );
function mx_price_per_installments_w_fee() {
    global $product;
 $price = (float) $product->get_price();
    $feeextended = (3/100) * $price;
    $price4extendedinstallments = $price - $feeextended;
   echo "
   <div id='installments-container'>
       <div id='installments-text'>
  <div class='bold'>Wire price: <span class='success'>". number_format($price4extendedinstallments, 2, ",", ".") ." €.</span></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ";
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'mx_price_per_installments_w_fee', 30  );
function mx_price_per_installments_w_fee() {
    global $product;
    $price = (float) $product->get_price();
    $feeextended = (3/100) * $price;
    $price4extendedinstallments = $price - $feeextended;
   echo "
   <div id='installments-container'>
       <div id='installments-text'>
        <div class='bold'>Wire price: <span class='success'>". number_format($price4extendedinstallments, 2, ",", ".") ." €.</span></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ";
}
```